# Customize Form Validation message

Tags: laravel-8

How to Customize Form Validation message in Laravel 8 ?

My Controller code is like below.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'option_price.0' => 'required|gt:0',
],$messages = ['option_price.gt:0' => 'Option price should be more than Zero.',]);


if ( $validator->fails() ) {
    return redirect()->route( 'vendor.add-option.add-new' )->withErrors( $validator )->withInput();
}
```

But I am not getting customize message.

Answer (score 1):

```
$messages = ['option_price.gt:0' => 'Option price should be more than Zero.',]
```

I think you should save it only in an array:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'option_price.0' => 'required|gt:0',
],['option_price.gt:0' => 'Option price should be more than Zero.']);
```

or you save it in a variable:

```
$messages = ['option_price.gt:0' => 'Option price should be more than Zero.']
```

and call only the variable $message in your validator.

Comment: Thanks @Firemarcel112. Your solution is not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Other way that you can try is following:

```
try {
 // your validation
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), 
 ['option_price.0' => 'required|gt:0',],
 ['option_price.gt:0' => 'Option price should be more than Zero.']);     

  // become errormessages from your validation
  $errors = $validate->errors()->messages(); 
  // loop your errors and throw as Exception, that makes sure your become all errors
  if($errors) {
    foreach($errors as $error) {
      throw new Exception($error[0]);
    }
  }

} cach(Exception $e) {
 
  return redirect()->route('vendor.add-option.add-new')->with("error" $e->getMessage());
}
```

In your View you can call

```
Session::get("error")
```

to show your errors

i think this solution should work better, tell me if this work :)